# Querying two tables for rows that exist between a date period

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm querying two tables and returning the dates that exists between a time period.

```
(

            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date
            FROM `users exercises`
            WHERE `userid` = $user->id AND (date >= '$begin' AND date <= '$end')
            GROUP BY day(date)
            ORDER BY date

            ) UNION ALL (

            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date
            FROM `users foods`
            WHERE `userid` = $user->id AND (date >= '$begin' AND date <= '$end')
            GROUP BY day(date)
            ORDER BY date

)
```

I'm currently using a `UNION` but I sense maybe there is a better method to achieve what I'm wanting?

Both the tables have the same structure:

```
id | userid | date (timestamp)
```

Comment: Are `userid` values unique in each table?

Comment: They're a foreign key, from a users table. Each user has it's own ID.

Comment: `GROUP BY DAY(date)` will only be right if the time range is less than a month. Otherwise you'll combine rows from the same day in different months.

Comment: One thing, if you dont want duplicates used UNION, it will remove duplicates, just saying

Comment: You can used GROUP BY day(date) & ORDER BY date at the end of the Union query once. No need to used it two times.

Comment: Just for fun, you could try doing the filtering AFTER the unioning, but this is OK. Strictly speaking you should GROUP BY the same thing you SELECT but I guess what you've got works too

Comment: The question is what do you want to achieve? The query gets you a list of dates, some of them repeatedly. What good does that do? This looks like a subquery in a more complex query, but what is its purpose?

Comment: Such query would be invalid in another DBMS, by the way. You group by day(date), but still access date in your select clause. Say you have 2015-04-01 and 2015-05-01 in your data, then for day 1 you'd get one of the two dates randomly picked by MySQL. Another DBMS would raise a syntax error message. It is a special feature in MySQL to allow this, and is both convenient and error-prone.